# Using Luigi within Django

Tags: python, django, luigi

I developed a pipeline with Luigi framework.

Now I would like to trigger it, within a webapp (Django), by pressing a button.

However, when I run the pipeline from the webapp, I get the following error:

> signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, self.handle_interrupt)
>
> ValueError: signal only works in main thread"

Here is my code:

```
def run_pipeline():
   p = Pipeline()
   exec p

def index_view(request):
    if request.GET.get('btnRun'):
        t = threading.Thread(target=run_pipeline)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: Take a look at [django-luigi](https://pypi.org/project/django-luigi/) it might help

Comment: Have you been able to succesfully use django-luigi?